# Group.ReadWrite.All scope clarification

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

My organization operates a shared Azure tenant between two separate organizations.

I have a requirement to provide a third party application (working on behalf of just one of the orgs) Delegated `Group.ReadWrite.All` permission to Microsoft Graph.

I am just being ultra-cautious about what this may mean in terms of the tenant and both organizations, and appreciate similar questions have been posted.

So my understanding is

1. `Group.ReadWrite.All` grants the application permission to write to the O365 Group Calendar and SharePoint Group, delegated which means the application can only access Graph via a valid signed in application user?
2. This means whatever the signed-in user cannot do, neither can the application?
3. This also means that if the signed-in user has no permissions to access anything on the second organization (SharePoint site; O365 calendar) then neither can the application?
4. It would only be bad practice e.g. ICT accidentally adding in the wrong user etc that would result in the application having more rights than it should?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is understandably confusing given this scope's `.All` suffix but your understanding is correct. It sometimes helps to use a fictitious user as an example.

Let's say we have two users, Bob and Sally:

- Sally is a member of the "Sales Executives" and "Corporate Leadership Team" groups.
- Bob is a member of the "Corporate Leadership Team" and "Finance Executives" groups.

If you provide *Delegated* `Group.ReadWrite.All` to the application:

- When Sally authenticates the application will only have access to the "Sales Executives" and "Corporate Leadership Team" groups. It would *not* have access to the "Finance Executives" group.
- When Bob authenticates the application will have access to the "Corporate Leadership Team" and "Finance Executives" groups but *not* "Sales Executives".

Delegated permissions give an application to operate on behalf of a User. Regardless of the scopes granted, the application will be limited to activities otherwise granted to the User.

Application permissions on the other hand operate only on their behalf. If you were to grant Application `Group.ReadWrite.All`, the app would have permission to access any Group in the tenant ([with some exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#groups)).